# Mutating array elements in reactive Publisher onNext/doOnNext methods

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, project-reactor

Is it safe to update array element from inside onNext? like shown in the below code:

```java
int[] arr = new int[0];
asyncMethod().map(item -> {
  arr[0] = arr[0] + item.length();
  if (arr[0] > MAX_TOTAL_LENGTH) {
    // throw an exception for crossing max total length limit
  }
  return item;
});
```

Do I need to synchronize arr since onNext can be called from multiple threads even though the call is serialized?

Answer (score 2):

Your example uses `map()` but you talk about using `onNext()` - though the answer is essentially the same.

> Is it safe to update array element from inside onNext?

Not without further guarantees - only if `arr` isn't used anywhere else, and you can guarantee `asyncMethod()` never returns a publisher that can execute in parallel. In parallel execution, it isn't safe as `arr[0] = arr[0] + item.length();` isn't an atomic operation (it would need to be synchronized on a suitable lock.) You also run into potential issues with the values in the array being cached on individual threads, causing further race hazards.

If you really wanted to go with this approach then `AtomicInteger` would be a better fit than an array, as that contains a method specifically designed to `addAndGet()` in a thread-safe manner.

Having said that, bear in mind that mutating "external" variables from inside a publisher's transformation function is almost always a code smell.

In the case that you feel the need to do this then there's almost certainly a better way - this is rather nasty code that's incredibly likely to catch someone out at some point.

In this example for instance, you're essentially doing a reduction - so (in reactor for instance) you'd be much better doing something akin to:

```
asyncMethod().reduce(0, (len, item) -> {
    int updatedLen = len + item.length();
    if(updatedLen > MAX_TOTAL_LENGTH) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Too long");
    }
    return updatedLen;
});
```

[RXJava has a similar reduce operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/reduce.html), as will nearly all reactive frameworks.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Michael.

arr is not used anywhere.

My understanding about well behaved publisher is - Whether it produce each value in separate threads or single thread, the downstream onNext calls won’t overlap even though they can get called from multiple thread. Effectively serializing the calls. Rx has an operator to take care of this serialization if needed http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/serialize.html. For such a well behaved stream, the “arr[0] = arr[0] + item.length();” will be atomic right?

Comment: @AnuThomasChandy It wouldn't be "atomic" as such, but it wouldn't pose an issue in that circumstance since it'd never be executed from more than one thread at any one time. I'm not sure if that definition of a "well behaved" publisher however is one shared across frameworks.

Comment: contract for "well behaved" publisher is described here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html. The serial nature of notification is described in this link as: "Observables must issue notifications to observers serially (not in parallel). They may issue these notifications from different threads, but there must be a formal happens-before relationship between the notifications."

Comment: @AnuThomasChandy Yup, but as far as I can tell, that's just "well behaved" as defined for the reactivex series of libraries (RXJava being the relevant one in this case.) I can't find anything obvious that says that same contract applies to all Java based reactive streams libraries.

Comment: I'm looking mainly the reactivex libs (RxJava, project-reactor) and it seems those frameworks adhere to this contract. In case of these frameworks, code block inside notification handlers are not overlapped. Now my main concern is around the visibility of shared data update (like arr in the question) across threads. Cores can cache values and delay the write back to memory which cause other threads to miss such updates.

Comment: @AnuThomasChandy Yes, you're correct to be worried about that. If you *really* want to do something like this then the `AtomicInteger` would be a much better fit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198902/discussion-between-michael-berry-and-anu-thomas-chandy).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you operate the flow. If your code sample is guaranteed externally to be called only once and there will be only one subscriber to it then it is okay.

Otherwise, the usage of `arr` indicates you need a variable inside `map` to decide on the subsequent items. `map` doesn't support per-subscriber state this way so you need to externalize the extra variables relative to the lambda as well as make sure each realization of the flow will get its own, non-conflicting instance. That's what `defer` is for:

```java
Observable.defer(() -> {
    int[] arr = new int[0];
    return asyncMethod().map(item -> {
        arr[0] = arr[0] + item.length();
        if (arr[0] > MAX_TOTAL_LENGTH) {
            // throw an exception for crossing max total length limit
        }
        return item;
    });
});
```

Here, each consumer will have its own fresh `map` created which then can reference the `arr` and manipulate it without clashing with any other consumer.

Comment: Thanks you David. Do we need to worry about visibility of "shared data" update across threads? My understanding is - cores can cache values and delay the write back to memory which cause other threads to miss such updates. 
if asyncMethod() returns an Observable backed by multiple threads then map function could to be called from multiple threads but of course serially, right? Can this cause update visibility issue?

Comment: Or should we use volatile? i.e.
In the above code replacing:
   int[] arr = new int[0];
with:
   volatile int currentLength = 0;

Comment: No. The lambda is called in serialized fashion and the library takes care of all memory visibility related work. There is no need for volatile/AtomicX usage in this case.

Comment: I'm a reader of your popular rx blog, is there somewhere in the blog you explain how this visibility is taken care? If so could you point it to me?

Comment: Read it from the beginning and read someone's post about the java memory model.